# Can we intend anything that exists and must it exist partly in that intention

Tags: phenomenology, husserl, nothing, being-and-time

Can we intend anything, even nothingness, or my own death, or an empty world?

And if so do these things exist in their intention, as something interior to the thought about them?

I ask because it seems to me that if I can have a thought about nothing which is nothing, then I can "die" while still living. That may seem very counter intuitive, but there is an hetrodox, but academic, reading of Being and Time which suggests that.

I would go as far as to say that then what these interpreters call "demise", my death as it is usually thought of, would then be an instance of that non existing thought of non existence. i.e. that "demise", being an instance of something that is not my demise, is impossible. But perhaps I botched the logic there, even granted the phenomenological question is OK.

Answer (score 2):

The possibility of existence "inside the intention" borders on paradox. Suppose X does not exist. And then I intend X. And then X exists (inside the intention). So that the X that I intend (which now exists) is not the same as the X before the intention (which did not exist). So that then it seems that I do not intend what I intended to intend (pun intended).

I wrote that it "borders" on paradox, because there are ways to escape the paradox. But they have their own prices. One familiar strategy (found in Meinung, also Descartes; and perhaps Heidegger) is to recognize two (or more) distinct kinds of existence. So that existence "inside the intention" is an existence of a special kind.